# Print view ignores stylesheet

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using a JQuery DataTables in a Ruby on Rails project and it does have a wonderful extension Buttons. This can export to PDF, Print, Excel or CVS and also support bootstrap.

I'm currently using Chrome Dev Tools to add directly the bootstrap classes "table table-striped table-bordered" to a  tag, and then run the following code snippet:

```
var tabla =  $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'print',
            autoPrint: false,
            customize: function ( win ) {
                $(win.document.body)
                    .css( 'font-size', '10pt' )
                    .prepend(
                        '<img src="http://datatables.net/media/images/logo-fade.png" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;" />'
                    );

                $(win.document.body).find( 'td' )
                    .addClass( 'compact' )
                    .css( 'font-size', 'inherit' )
                    .css( 'border-color, 'gray'  );
            }
        }
    ]
} );
```

Unfortunately the print preview is not styled at all. The print button opens a new window with customized style (via .css method) and is okay there, the problem is **when you hit ctrl-p to preview print, the style `.css( 'border-color, 'gray'  )` applied to 'td' tag is completely ignored**.

I suspect that the problem is related to bootstrap, I watch the Chrome Inspector and I notice that media queries are for "screen", but not for print.

Is there a way to include a media query for print using the method above?

**Update**: After reading a example of a Media Query for Print from W3Schools and executed code in a JsBin, I found that just by adding bootstrap library, media query print stops working. Is there a way a override that behaviour? Is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, bootstrap is loaded with the tag `media="screen"` by default in print view, so the only way to override this is by adding this in customize:

```
{
                extend: 'print',
                autoPrint: true,
                customize: function ( win ) {
                    $(win.document.body)
                        .css( 'font-size', '10pt' );

                    $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
                        .addClass( 'compact' )
                        .css( 'font-size', 'inherit' );
                     var medias = win.document.querySelectorAll('[media="screen"]');
                     for(var i=0; i < medias.length;i++){ medias.item(i).media="all" };
                }
            }
```

That selects all tags that have the media attribute and change them to "all" to make them visible in print view.

Comment: I am having issue while printing can you help me out please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776387/formatting-the-output-of-datatable-when-there-are-filters-around-it